# Highcharts background color based on x y

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I'm working on makin a graph like this in highcharts:
[image]

But I have problems making the green red yellow background colors based on y and x axis.

This is an example I have found but it's only based on the y axis: jsfiddle.net/tK7ux
And I want to use plotBands on both X and Y at the same time, if possible.

Maybe there is another way than using plotBands ? i have also looked at Renderer functions and making an rectangle, but the problem was that it is the position not is based on the Y and X axis.

Comment: sorry about the link that not is a link to  http://jsfiddle.net/tK7ux

Comment: PlotBands won't work for you, since you can use x-plotBand or y-plotBand, not xy-plotBand. To use renderer with value positions, use [`Axis.toPixels()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels) method. Like this: `chart.renderer.rect(x, y, w, h)`, where `var x = chart.xAxis.toPixels(x_value, true);` etc. Of course `x_value` for categorized xAxis should be index of the category. In your case, for example Mar is equal to 2.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I will focus on using toPixels than.

Comment: did you succeed? can you share the solution if possible as I am also stuck with the same problem

Comment: @Ramgaard Hi did you manage this, got any code?